# Put into a chart the values of the city selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, charts, google-visualization

I have a **json** data in this format:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.cities = [{
        name: "city A",
        elements: [{
          id: 'c01',
          name: 'name1',
          price: 15,
          qte: 10
        }, {
          id: 'c02',
          name: 'name2',
          price: 18,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'c03',
          name: 'name3',
          price: 11,
          qte: 14
        }],
        subsities: [{
          name: "sub A1",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sub01',
            name: 'nameSub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }, {
            id: 'sub02',
            name: 'nameSub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 13
          }, {
            id: 'sub03',
            name: 'nameSub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 14
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A2",
          elements: [{
            id: 'ssub01',
            name: 'nameSsub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 7
          }, {
            id: 'ssub02',
            name: 'nameSsub2',
            price: 8,
            qte: 1
          }, {
            id: 'ssub03',
            name: 'nameSsub3',
            price: 4,
            qte: 19
          }]
        }, {
          name: "sub A3",
          elements: [{
            id: 'sssub01',
            name: 'nameSssub1',
            price: 1,
            qte: 11
          }, {
            id: 'sssub02',
            name: 'nameSssub2',
            price: 2,
            qte: 15
          }, {
            id: 'sssub03',
            name: 'nameSssub3',
            price: 1,
            qte: 15
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city B",
        elements: [{
          id: 'cc01',
          name: 'name11',
          price: 10,
          qte: 11
        }, {
          id: 'cc02',
          name: 'name22',
          price: 14,
          qte: 19
        }, {
          id: 'cc03',
          name: 'name33',
          price: 11,
          qte: 18
        }]
      }, {
        name: "city C",
        elements: [{
          id: 'ccc01',
          name: 'name111',
          price: 19,
          qte: 12
        }, {
          id: 'ccc02',
          name: 'name222',
          price: 18,
          qte: 17
        }, {
          id: 'ccc03',
          name: 'name333',
          price: 10,
          qte: 5
        }]
      }];
      $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
        if (itemSelected && itemSelected.elements) {
          $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
        }
      }
    });
```

I put them into a table, I put the value of city or subcity selected into a table and I want to put them in a chart too for data will be more readable.

**The HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedCity)" ng-options="item as item.name for item in cities track by item.name">
  </select>

  <select ng-show="selectedCity.subsities" ng-model="selectedSubCity" ng-change="extractSubsities(selectedSubCity)" ng-options="item2 as item2.name for item2 in selectedCity.subsities track by item2.name">
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item3 in data track by item3.id">
      <!--but here I need to iterat the selectedSubCity too when I select DropDown 2-->
      <td>{{ item3.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ item3.qte}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

the user can chose the city or subcity and then can read data from table or chart like the chart below:

[image]
 help please I can't make it work.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a chart? Look at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart or other similar libraries

Comment: @jessegavin yes how to create a chart base on the value of the city selected for example 'city A'

Comment: @jessegavin I saw your link interessting but I need to integrat it into my code any help please

Comment: This library provides angular directives for Chart.js http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#bar-chart

They have code examples and everything.